# Javascript, syntax after function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that changes an object for me and I'm wondering how a bit of it works and would be grateful if someone could explain it or point me in the right direction. Here is the function:

```
$scope.filteredObject = Object.keys($scope.filterObject).reduce(function(p, collection) {
    var values = $scope.filterObject[collection];
    p[collection] = Object.keys(values).filter(function(key) {
        return values[key] === true;
    }).map(function(key) {
        return key;
    });
    return p;
}, {});
```

So this works great, but I'm wondering what the `}, {});` at the end of the function does exactly. Im not exactly sure the name of that and googleing "*`}, {}` after a function in javascript*" seems to confuse the hell out of google (lol). Thanks!

Comment: It's `.reduce(function(p, collection) { ... }, {});` In other words, the rest of the `.reduce()` function call.

Comment: The anonymous function and the empty object (`{}`) are parameters to the `reduce` function.

Comment: [MDN Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `}` - end of the anoymous function expression `function(p, collection) { … }`
- `,` - delimiter between multiple arguments
- `{}` - (empty) [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer),  the second argument
- `)` - end of function invocation, closing parentheses for the arguments list to [`.reduce(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1):

It is an empty object and has nothing to do with the function.
Have a look at the [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

The reduce function has a second optional parameter.

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

So in your case it's like this:

```
callback = function(p, collection) { /*...*/ };
initialValue = {}; // could also be new Object()
```

Hope this helps :)